# Do people really look for Users that often that it deserves its own tab in the iOS app?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, ios-app

I only got into the iOS app beta a couple of days ago and my first reaction was "Do people really look for other users on the site that often that it deserves to be a main navigation item?"

I know that the feature also exists on the site but I never use it myself. Do other people use it that much?

I bet there is something more useful that we can put there. Maybe questions that have a bounty? I use that much more than I look for users. Or what about reviews or other moderation tools?

I'm not saying that the feature shouldn't exist. I'm just saying in my opinion it belongs in the hamburger menu to the left.

---

To be clear, I'm talking about this thing:

[image]

Comment: Downvote probably indicates disagreement. Personally I see your point; the users tab is only really trivia (who is the jon skeet on this site) and I don't use it very often.  But equally it incentives *being* the jon skeet of the site

Comment: @RichardTingle Thanks for the clarification. I'm still not used to MSO

Comment: Finding the contributions/profile of a specific user is arguably a necessity, far more than trivia.

Comment: @David it does take some getting used to; it's very different to the rest of the network

Comment: @Pekka, the only *necessity* I can think of is as it relates to a particular post. You can tap the user on the post to get to the profile...

Comment: Counter-question: As an entity, are users really *that much less significant* than the other entities in the system (like questions, tags and badges), that they *don't* deserve their own tab?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Maybe not less significant but in my opinion certainly less *frequently used*.

Comment: Perhaps the real problem is that there's not much functionality in that page.

Comment: As for your Edit #2, the menu to the left is for global, outside of particular sites, so I don't think it makes sense there. Maybe there's room for a fifth tab button? Or maybe we could finally have a way to *search* for bounty questions?

Comment: Do you really only find this a problem in the iOS app? Then maybe add a (partial) screenshot of that? (I only noticed that tag while editing, so I gave that some more emphasis.)

Comment: @Arjan, it's a problem in the iOS app because there's not enough real estate for every choice. There are four tabs: Questions, Users, Tags, Ask

Comment: Yeah, @mhlester, that's what I expected. I'm afraid though that many readers (downvoters) of the first revisions might not have realised it was about that app. A screenshot would make that very clear... :-)

Comment: @David, this is sort of status-completed in the latest beta!

Comment: @mhlester spoilers ;) Yeah, this view should be a lot more user friendly soon.

Comment: Since I implemented the editable tab bar almost a year ago, I should have probably marked this a [tag:status-completed] a lot sooner.

Answer (score 7):

> Do people really look for Users that often that it deserves to be it's own tab?

I don't know, but it arguably deserves a position as prominent as "questions" and "tags".

While it may not be relevant for you, it is for others. All the arguments that can be made against the "users" page can be made against every other page up there.

Possible uses for the "users" tab include:

- looking up what/how a specific user is doing.
- looking for an interesting contribution where you only remember it was from a specific user.
- looking for the contact info of a user you had been in contact with.
- monitoring a problem user's recent activity.
- Trivial stuff like seeing who is on page 1, what countries people there come from, etc.

Comment: ... finding out who is selling genuine Gucci Handbags.

Comment: @Robert would like my baseball many free gucci selling now online cheap www.goochee.com

Comment: @RobertHarvey They're not genuine. They're discounted.

Comment: @Mysticial Discount Gucci Handbags can be genuine **and** discounted. Please remove your comment or my lawyers will be in touch

Answer (score 4):

You know, there is room to have your cake and eat it too:

> [image]

Or do like the Music app does, and provide a `...` on the right for choosing the buttons you want to see.

---

### Edit

So like it or not, this looks to have been implemented exactly as my second suggestion:

> [image]
> SE iOS app beta **1.0.1.80**

It's got some bugs to work out, and new tabs will be needed, but the key framework is now there.

---

As for finding featured questions, I've given that more thought. I think that actually makes the most sense as a sort/filter selection within the Questions tab, as it would need to be within whatever tags you're viewing.

Comment: There is already a hamburger menu in the top left. I don't think there is any need for a "..." menu as well.

Comment: are you talking about the sidebar where you choose a site?

Comment: Yes. I know that they would have very different functionality but it would look ridiculous with two "more" menus on the screen at once.

Comment: The problem is the sidebar is used for network-wide items. specific to the site you're pretty much limited to the tab bar.

Answer (score 3):

I use the "users" page a lot, for (among things):

- answering questions like "who here can actually cast delete votes?" and "who's close to such-and-such privilege who we should be ready to guide?"
- seeing who's rising in reputation, both lately and overall
- as a shortcut to the moderators' user pages
- seeing who our newest users are; these are the ones who might need a little extra guidance
- finding a specific user for one of the reasons listed in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/229474/162102)

On large sites maybe none of this matters, but on small sites -- and, I would think, any beta site -- being aware of and building the community is important.

Comment: "it's the "featured" tab on the questions view." Are you really talking about the iOS app now because I can't find it?

Comment: Oh, sorry -- missed the tag!  I'll remove that part.  (What I said is true of the web site.)

Answer (score 1):

As currently constituted, I don't think it is necessary.  It only takes me a little while to find myself on the list (but I'm lucky). I can't see how to find another user by searching, or how to scroll to a new page, or how to see this week's reputation vs this month's etc.