# Reduce number of taps to get to commonly used screens

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, ios-app

So I open the app fresh, and it opens me to the feed page. The feed page has "hot" and "interesting" using half the real estate, except the interesting section has 5 sites that I do not use, I've only been to one of them once. But that's [a topic for another thread.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220387/how-can-i-prevent-the-app-from-showing-interesting-questions-from-sites-i-don)

So I use two taps to scroll over to StackOverflow, where I actually want to be. Not too bad. This puts me on the "active" page, which has four questions in languages I don't know and am not interested in. Okay, this is how the website works anyway, no big deal.

- Taps: 2. (Website clicks: 0) (3 and 1 if you count opening the app and clicking on a bookmark)

On the main site, my favorite tags are on the right sidebar, so I click one of them and now I have questions I want to read. Great. However, we're talking about the iOS App. So I click **Tags**, and am rewarded with a list of every tag on StackOverflow.

- Taps: 3 (Website clicks: 1)

If I want a tag less popular than [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby), I have to wait for the page to load. Less popular than [multithreading](/questions/tagged/multithreading), I have to wait for it to load twice. My favorite tags are nowhere in sight. Fortunately for me, the tag I'm looking for is [java](/questions/tagged/java), so I'm one of the lucky ones.

- Taps: 4 (Website clicks: 1)

This pulls me to what's effectively the search results page, so the default tab is the **Relevant** page. I've already read [Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array) and [Why is subtracting these two times (in 1927) giving a strange result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result) so these are not interesting to me. They were interesting the first time, but not exactly what I'm looking to read. In comparison, the website shows the tab I looked at last (which is usually **Newest** or **Active**), both of which are more meaningful.

- Taps: 6 (with or without a tag load) (Website clicks: 1)

6 taps to get to useful information is too much. I'd rather use a bookmark and the mobile website skin.

How we can improve this:

1. Provide easy access to favorite tags when you first load a StackExchange site.
2. Remove **Users** from the bottom scroll bar. I don't think I've ever clicked on it on the main site, and, honestly, how many times do I need to see that Jon Skeet has the most reputation on StackOverflow?

   - Instead, replace it with something like **Favorites**
3. When you click on a tag on the **Tags** page, the default sort should either be your most recently used sort, or at the very least **Active** or **Newest**.

Comment: I assume at some point the ability to see different feeds will appear?  That's the main problem - you can easily get a Feed with your favorite tags in it, but I don't think you can show it in iOS.

Comment: This is kind of a dupe of two different posts: [Favorite tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226906/filter-tag-list-to-my-favorites-in-app) and [remember sort choice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229101/persist-sort-filter-selections)

Comment: Also related: [Add a front-page-like tab to the iOS app's main site view](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229706)

Comment: While we're at it: [removing the users tab](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229472/do-people-really-look-for-users-that-often-that-it-deserves-its-own-tab-in-the-i)

Comment: @mhlester Fair, but this question emphasizes how all those other questions together makes the app ultimately too cumbersome to use. In other words, this question is "walk with me through the usability of the app", the other questions are "I would like to have XYZ feature"

Comment: Totally agree. This post is probably too broad. I fell in the same trap before too: [Don't go modal in app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228682/dont-go-modal-in-app-search)

Comment: @mhlester I just upvoted everything, haha. I don't think this should be closed, but that's what voting and close votes are for :)

Comment: Ha! I don't see anyone downvoting or closing this yet, and certainly not me. As for the upvotes, thanks but they'll probably be reversed as serial upvoting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post was way ahead of its time.  Various feature requests have been completed since and knocked out many of these features.

Skipping some exposition:

> On the main site, my favorite tags are on the right sidebar, so I click one of them and now I have questions I want to read. Great. However, we're talking about the iOS App. So I click Tags, and am rewarded with a list of every tag on StackOverflow. ... My favorite tags are nowhere in sight.
>
> Taps: 4 (Website clicks: 1)

A couple features knock this out.  First, you can now reorder your tabs so Tags is your first tab.  That way, every time you visit the site you instantly have the tag list.  Next, you can change your sort order to "Favorite" showing your favorite tags.  Since your sort order is saved, every time you go to Stack Overflow you will see your favorite tags. **(2 taps)**

Alternatively, if you don't want to reorder your tabs, simply tapping the search field on questions will bring up recent searches, saved searches, and a list of your favorite tags.  It's one extra tap but you get was is essentially bookmarked searches. **(3 taps)**

> This pulls me to what's effectively the search results page, so the default tab is the Relevant page. ... In comparison, the website shows the tab I looked at last (which is usually Newest or Active), both of which are more meaningful.

We are actually still doing this. While it uses the last sort order you used on a tags page it defaulted to "Relevant".  I'm changing this to Newest to match the web.  It'll be in the next build. **(3 taps for tag list, 4 taps for question search)**

Comment: Thanks Brian! Quick question, if I'm still using the beta version, does that mean I have the "next build" already or the next beta build?

Comment: @durron597 It'll be in the next beta build, but you may never see the change.  If you've already viewed questions from a tag and changed the sort, that value has been saved so you should never see the built-in default.

Comment: I'll be honest, this issue soured me on the app for quite awhile, I haven't used the app for anything beyond reading & replying to notifications in a really long time. But this answer has inspired me to try again!